# How much structure forces vector space structure?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a non-empty set and let $F$ be a field. An abstract $F$-vector space structure on $V$ consists of

- an addition $+_V$ on $V$ such that

**(A1) $+_V$ is associative**

**(A2) $+_V$ has a neutral element $0_V$**

**(A3) $+_V$ has inverse elements**

**(A4) $+_V$ is commutative**

- and an $F$-scalar multiplication $\cdot$ on $V$ such that

**(S1) $\cdot$ is associative over $V$**

**(S2) $1_F$ is (left-)neutral wrt. $\cdot$**

- satisfying the consistency relations

**(C1) $\cdot$ is distributive over $+_V$**

**(C2) $\cdot$ is distributive over $+_F$**

I'm wondering how much redundancy is involved here. The commutativity in (A4) can be shown to follow from $(-1_F\cdot v=-v)$, which in turns follows from a combination of S- and C-axioms. I guess we cannot deduce associativity from anything. What other implications hold between the axioms? Can perhaps any of the S- and C-axioms be formally weakened (or completely dropped) so as to preserve the vector space structure? What is a "minimal" set of formal requirements on $+_V$ and $\cdot$ that still forces the full vector space structure?

Comment: Why do you think that commutativity of vector addition, i.e., the property $\forall u,v \in V : u + v = v + u$, follows from $-1_F \cdot v = -v$?

Comment: Well, in combination with the other axioms of course: we get that $-(v+u)=...=-v+(-u)$, then adding $u+v$ on both sides gives the result?